# How to find the maximum value in the array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Suppose there is a list of users. And in this list there is a `date` value that has the data type `Date` or `string`. And if  use a function that will display all users:

```
  users: User[]
  private loadUsers() {
    this.usersService.fetch().subscribe(
      users => {
        this.users = users
      }
   )
 }
```

How can  use this function to filter the data so that the user with the highest `date` is displayed.

Comment: Depends on the date format.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the question is really unclear. you didn't add about the user object structure and also any code about your trying.

Comment: @kyl The structure is not needed here, I just need to find the maximum date (if the date is the data type string or DATE) of the user

Comment: Do you want to find one user who has high date value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this array sort function will help you.

```
var dates = [
  new Date('2013-1-1'),
  new Date('2012-1-1'),
  new Date('2014-1-1'),
  new Date('2015-1-1'),
  new Date('2016-1-1'),
  new Date('2017-1-1'),
  new Date('2018-1-1')
];

dates.sort((d1, d2) => {
  if(d1<d2)
    return -1;
  else if(d1>d2)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
});

console.log(dates[dates.length-1]);
```

codepen link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLxMja

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too,

```
var dates = [
  new Date('2013-1-1'),
  new Date('2012-1-1'),
  new Date('2014-1-1'),
  new Date('2015-1-1'),
  new Date('2016-1-1'),
  new Date('2017-1-1'),
  new Date('2018-1-1')
];

console.log(Math.max(...dates));
```